# How to initialize Swift class annotated @MainActor for XCTest, SwiftUI Previews, etc

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, mainactor

We'd like to make use of the `@MainActor` Annotation for our ViewModels in an existing SwiftUI project, so we can get rid of `DispatchQueue.main.async` and `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)`.

```
@MainActor
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var counter: Int
    init(counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter
    }
}
```

This works fine when initializing the annotated class from a SwiftUI View. However, when using a SwiftUI Previews or XCTest we also need to initialize the class from outside of the `@MainActor` context:

```
class MyViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

    private var myViewModel: MyViewModel!
    
    override func setUp() {
        myViewModel = MyViewModel(counter: 0)
    }
```

Which obviously doesn't compile:

> Main actor-isolated property 'init(counter:Int)' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context

Now, obviously we could also annotate `MyViewModelTests` with `@MainActor` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139689/how-do-i-construct-a-swiftui-class-annotated-mainactor-in-preview).

But we don't want all our UnitTests to run on the main thread. So what is the recommended practice in this situation?

Annotating the `init` function with `nonisolated` as also suggested in the conversation above only works, if we don't want to set the value of variables inside the initializer.

Comment: Why do you have view models in SwiftUI? That is what the View struct is for.

Comment: Let's not turn this in an SwiftUI architecture discussion. There's good reasons to use View Structs for handling service/logic calls and there's good reasons to use ViewModels instead.

Comment: I’ve not heard a good reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just mark `setUp()` as @MainActor

```
class MyViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    private var myViewModel: MyViewModel!

    @MainActor override func setUp() {
        myViewModel = MyViewModel(counter: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: That sure would work. However setUp() is called before every single test case, so there would still be a lot of work done one the main thread. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 6):

## Approach:

- You can use `override func setUp() async throws` instead

## Model:

```
@MainActor
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var counter: Int
    
    init(counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter
    }
    
    func set(counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter
    }
}
```

## Testcase:

```
import XCTest
@testable import Demo

final class MyViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    private var myViewModel: MyViewModel!
    
    override func setUp() async throws {
        myViewModel = await MyViewModel(counter: 10)
    }
    
    override func tearDown() async throws {
        myViewModel = nil
    }

    func testExample() async throws {
        await myViewModel.set(counter: 20)
    }
}
```